# Magento 2 how to redirect to checkout on ajax submit?

Tags: magento2, redirect, checkout-page

I'm trying to redirect a form to checkout after clicking ajax submit request.

I'm able to reach the controller, but I can't redirect to checkout.

Here is my code:

```
 public function execute(){
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if($post){
            $this->logger->info(print_r($post)); 
            $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();            
            exit;
        }
         else{
            $this->logger->info("No data");   
         }
    
    }
```

It's not redirecting to checkout

I'm using  `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your ajax success function you can use jquery code

for e.g.
window.location.href='your checkout url';

Comment: thanks! I don't know why I tried to do it from controller.